# Data table issue while rendering the shiny page <DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown parameter>

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am facing an issue with my shiny app, where columnar data rendered from a csv file is displayed in rows instead of columns (Each variable except the header is being treated as a column, whereas it should be aligned in row). Every time I access the shiny page it pops up the following Error: "DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown parameter '10' for row 10. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4". Please see the attached image below

The same application with the exact same code is running absolutely fine in the quality cluster and fails in the production. Both landscapes are exactly the same. Please see the two image below of how the data should look and how it currently is being displayed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2Gtv.png)

The application is running in on RHEL 7 with R 3.6

```
Server.R

shinyServer(function(session,input, output) {
  myAnalysisList = reactiveFileReader(1000, NULL, "scheduledAnalyses.csv", readFunc = read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")

  observeEvent(input$schedule,{

    tryCatch({

      adjustedDateRange<-getAdjustedDateRange(input$dateRange[1],input$dateRange[2],type = input$forecastType)
      currTime = Sys.time()
      print(input$forecastHorizon)
      forecastHorizonCorrected = input$forecastHorizon
      if(input$forecastType!="Monthly"){
        forecastHorizonCorrected = input$forecastHorizonWeekly
      }

      newRow = data.frame(ScheduledAt = as.character(currTime), 
                          StartDate = as.character(adjustedDateRange$startDate),
                          EndDate = as.character(adjustedDateRange$endDate),
                          Linea = input$productLinea,
                          Series = input$productSeries,
                          Group = input$productGroup,
                          StatGroup = input$productStatGroup,
                          ProductCode = input$productCode,
                          DemProfile = input$demandProfileSelected,
                          FType = input$forecastType,
                          FHorizon = forecastHorizonCorrected,
                          Status = "Scheduled",
                          Duration = 0)

      msg="Just before writing the Schedule"
      write.table(newRow,"scheduledAnalyses.csv",sep = "," ,row.names = FALSE,append = TRUE,col.names = FALSE)
      output$scheduleStatus = renderUI({
        box(title = "Status : Success",status = "success",width =NULL,solidHeader = TRUE,paste("Process has been scheduled at ",currTime, " ",format(currTime, format = "%Z")))
      })

    }, error = function(errorMsg){
      output$scheduleStatus = renderUI({
        box(title = "Status : Error",status = "danger", solidHeader = TRUE ,paste("Unable to schedule the process!\n Error: ",errorMsg$message,msg))
      })

    })

    #myAnalysisList <<- bind_rows(myAnalysisList,newRow)
    output$analysesList <- renderDataTable(myAnalysisList())


  })
  output$analysesList = renderDataTable(myAnalysisList())
  # observeEvent(input$forecastHorizon,{
  #   print(input$forecastHorizon)
  # })
```

UI.R

```
inp<-read.csv("inp.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#-------------------------Loading data from Spark ---------------------------------#
#tbl_cache(sc,"demand_forecast_newcode_monthyr")
#inpPtr<-tbl(sc,"demand_forecast_newcode_duedate") %>% filter(linea == "Linea Differenziali DS271" | linea == "Linea Differenziali Elettronici DSE201" | linea == "Linea Differenziali Puri F200" )
#inp<-collect(inpPtr)
#columnNames<-colnames(inp)
#newNames<-sub("^.*\\.","",columnNames)
#colnames(inp)<-newNames
#View(inp)
inp<- inp[!is.na(inp$due_date), ]
inp<- inp[!is.na(inp$linea), ]
inp<- inp[!is.na(inp$series), ]
inp<- inp[!is.na(inp$groupo), ]
inp<- inp[!is.na(inp$gruppo_stat), ]
inp<- inp[!is.na(inp$productcode), ]
inp$due_date <- as.Date(inp$due_date, origin = "1970-01-01")
inpmod <- inp %>% 
  mutate(Year = year(due_date),
         Month = month(due_date),
         MonthlyDate = format(due_date, format= "%Y-%m-01"),
         QuarterlyDate = quarter(due_date,with_year = TRUE),
         SemesterDate = semester(due_date,with_year = TRUE),
         WeekInYear = isoweek(due_date)
  )

lineaChoices = c("All",unique(inpmod$linea))
serieChoices = c("All",unique(inpmod$series))
groupChoices = c("All",unique(inpmod$groupo))
statGroupChoices = c("All",unique(inpmod$gruppo_stat))
productCodeChoices = c("All",unique(inpmod$materiale))
# Define UI for application that plots random distributions 
shinyUI(dashboardPage( 
  skin="red",

  dashboardHeader(title = "Demand Forecasting, ABB Inc.", titleWidth = 350),

  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem( "Forecast", tabName = "forecastTab", icon = icon("line-chart")),
      menuItem( "Status", tabName = "statusTab", icon = icon("cogs"))
    )
  ), 

  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem( tabName = "forecastTab",
               fluidRow(
                 column( width = 8,
                         fluidRow(
                           column( width = 12,
                                   box(title = "Timeline",  status = "danger", width = NULL,
                                       dateRangeInput("dateRange","Date Range(MM-YYYY):", format = "MM-yyyy", 
                                                      startview = "decade", start = "2010-01-01",end = Sys.Date())
                                       #tags$br(),
                                       #textOutput("AdjustedDate")
                                   )
                           )
                         ),
                         fluidRow(
                           column( width =12, 
                                   box(title = "Product Hierarchy",  status = "danger", width = NULL,
                                       column(width =  6,
                                              selectInput("productLinea","Linea", selectize = TRUE,
                                                          choices = lineaChoices, selected = "All"),
                                              tags$br(),
                                              selectInput("productGroup","Group",selectize = TRUE,
                                                          choices = statGroupChoices, selected = "All"),

                                              tags$br(),
                                              selectInput("productCode","Product Code",selectize = TRUE,
                                                          choices =productCodeChoices, selected = "All")

                                       ),
                                       column(width = 6,
                                              selectInput("productSeries","Series",selectize = TRUE,
                                                          choices = serieChoices, selected = "All"),
                                              tags$br(),
                                              selectInput("productStatGroup","Statistical Group", selectize = TRUE,
                                                          choices = groupChoices, selected = "All")


                                       )
                                   )
                           )
                         )
                 ),

                 column( width = 4,
                         box( title = "Forecast Parameters", status = "danger", width = NULL,
                              tags$br(),
                              selectInput("demandProfileSelected","Demand Profile",
                                          choices = c("Predictable", "Unstable", "All"), selected = "Predictable"),
                              #tags$h4("Select the required granularity for the forecast"),
                              tags$br(),
                              selectInput("forecastType","Forecast Type", choices = c("Monthly","Weekly"),
                                          selected = "Monthly"),
                              tags$hr(),
                              tags$br(),
                              #tags$h4("Select the number of time periods from end date to forecast"),
                              #tags$br(),
                              conditionalPanel("input.forecastType=='Monthly'",
                                               sliderInput("forecastHorizon", "Forecast Horizon:", 1, 12, 6)),
                              conditionalPanel("input.forecastType=='Weekly'",
                                               sliderInput("forecastHorizonWeekly", "Forecast Horizon:", 1, 52, 12))
                         ) 



                 )
               ),

               fluidRow(
                 column(width = 2,
                        actionButton("clear"," Clear", class = "btn-lg btn-success",
                                     style='color: white; width:100%; height:70px; font-size:150%;',
                                     icon = icon("refresh"))
                 ),
                 column(width = 3,

                        actionButton("schedule","  Schedule & Start", class = "btn-lg",
                                     style='color: white; background-color: #dd4b39; width:100%; height:70px; font-size:150%;',
                                     icon = icon("cogs")) 
                 )
                 # column(width = 8,
                 #        uiOutput("scheduleStatus")
                 # )
               ),
               fluidRow(
                 tags$br(),
                 column(width = 3),
                 column( width = 6, 
                         uiOutput("scheduleStatus")
                 )
               )

      ),

      tabItem(tabName = "statusTab",
              #p("COmiNg sOoN")
              fluidRow(
                column(12,
                       box(title = "Scheduled Forecasts",  status = "danger", width = NULL,
                           dataTableOutput('analysesList')
                       )
                )
              )
      )
    )
  )
))
```

Comment: Your code is huge. Could you try to post a minimal code that reproduces the issue ? SO members are not motivated if the code is so long.

Comment: hello Stephane, I have removed the sections of code not associated with the issue. Also, the specific issue I am encountering is only on the status tab of the shiny application. Not sure if it helps, but if I manually change all the values of the input variables to integer I do not get this error, whereas even if one of the input variables contains a character the "status" tab throws the data table error and each charecter of a single input value is trated as seperate column input.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, Thank you for the note. As a beginner, I think it's helpful for new members to post questions/issues accurately and concisely. :) FYI, I posted the solution to this issue for the community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please find the answer to this problem in the link below. Courtesy @andresrcs (https://community.rstudio.com/)

https://community.rstudio.com/t/data-table-issue-while-rendering-the-shiny-page-datatables-warning-table-id-datatables-table-0-requested-unknown-parameter/44016/3?u=pranav

Original discussion on the issues and proposed solution can be found here:
https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2653

Solution Synopsis: (the one that I tested and worked)
using DT package instead of shiny for renderDataTable() and dataTableOutput()

Many thanks to all, who contributed for the issue resolution. :)